# Loopback 4 - undocumented model property

Tags: loopback4

Is it possible to have an undocumented (private) property within a Loopback model? I would like clients to be able to pass values for the property in request bodies but I would like to remove the property from the Open API specification / docs.

Ideally, something like this:

```
  @property.array(UserRole, {
    description: 'Who has access to the contract.',
    hidden: true,
    documented: false,
  })
  userRoles: UserRole[];
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide certain API endpoints from swagger LoopBack4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60337547/hide-certain-api-endpoints-from-swagger-loopback4)

Comment: No, that applies to endpoints - here I am trying to exclude properties on the request model from the documentation.